# How do I kill a process in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Say I'm running a python script that doesn't exit properly. The powershell console does not return control to me without having to close the shell and open a new one. With Bash I can simply press Control-C to kill any process. What am I missing here?

Windows 8.1 Powershell

Comment: Tried Ctrl-Break yet? If that doesn't work your only recourse is to kill the process from the outside (not the shell itself, the Python interpreter).

Comment: You are missing Ctrl+Break

Comment: Apparently neither of my machines have the "break" key. ctrl-fn-Shift worked on my Z-Book, but my Mac with windows still will not terminate

Answer (score 9):

To kill a process, you can use the command [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process).

Or you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following   `stop-service <service>` choose a flag like `-force` to force stop even if it has dependent services as well.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-5.1